# How to add a loading image

Tags: jsp

I have a java web application using spring mvc(I didnt use hibernate,struts).

In my application, a jsp page is opened when I click a link. The jsp page displays data from a live database. When the page is opened, calculations are done (10 sec) and jsp page is rendered (2 sec).

I tried adding a redirect page containing a "loading" gif image but the image gets stuck when the page is redirected (the page is redirected after 1 sec).

I want the loading image to be smooth until the jsp page is loaded. Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loading gif should be on the same page that displays data.

Create a new page and let the Gif and Report.jsp be defined on that page.

Example:

1. create report-container.jsp
2. make it have following lines

   `<div id="loadingImg" style="display:block;height:100%">
       <img  src="loading.gif">
    </div>
    <jsp:include page="report.jsp">`
3. In report.jsp, add a line at the very end:

   `<script>
   if (document.getElementById("loadingImg"))   {
   // change the "display" css style to "none".
   }</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of redirection logic you try with jsps is not going to work consitently. 
Your best bet is to use ajax to get the response from your server and render it dynamically:

1. User clicks redirects to report.jsp
2. In report.jsp you show your loading image
3. report.jsp requests the report data from server using ajax
4. Once the data is avaialable, render it in the body and hide loading image